# android google analytics recommended dispatch interval

Tags: android, google-analytics

You can manually configure the interval where analytics will be sent to server using:

GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(interval);

The default is 30 minutes(btw, in ios it's 2 minutes).

My question is what is the recommended dispatch interval, and is there a downside of just sending it every, lets say 10 seconds?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a trade-off. The smaller your `dispatch interval` the more `real-time` your analytics data will be at the cost of `increased battery usage` to send the data to Google over the network more frequently.